# n digit numbers are formed using the digits 1,2,3,4 each of which begin with 1 such that no two consecutive digits are same

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

$n$ digit numbers are formed using the digits $1,2,3,4$ each of which begin with $1$ such that no two consecutive digits are same. If $a_n(n \ge 2)$ be such that $n$-digit numbers which ends in $1$ while $b_n$ be the ones which ends in a fixed number other than $1$, then
the value of $a_7$ is?

> I am in high school, have not been taught advanced mathematics and number theory. How to proceed with the question? I am struggling making a relation between $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: As a way to get started:  note that removing the final $1$ from a string of type $a_n$ gives a string of type $b_{n-1}(k)$ for $k\in \{2,3,4\}$, where $b_n(k)$ means good strings of length $n$ ending in $k$,    Similarly, appending a $1$ to any string of type $b_{n-1}(k)$ gives a string of type $a_n$.

Comment: As another hint:  it's easy to count the total number of good strings, which is also equal to $a_n+3b_n$.